# HTML5 Audio Recording

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, web-audio-api, recorder.js

I wanted to use the plugin for Audio Capturing in a recent project. I found Matt Diamond's effort with a [demo here](https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html) as most of the articles point here . I tried recreating this very same demo locally but no luck.

I included every dependency like demo's. Aslo changed the WorkerPath in recorder.js but nothing seems to work.

Please share your experiences. Any pointer to solution is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a codepen with tried code?

Comment: Thanks Asim for your time. You can view the demo's page source. I have the exact same thing. With same directory structure.

Comment: Do you have any error in console? Sometimes the browser stops you from referring external local files, when you open the plain html. Are you serving the files from a server?

Comment: No i also checked there already. Console is crystal clear.

Comment: Are you serving the files from a server? Checkout this https://github.com/chris-rudmin/Recorderjs

Comment: No, when we open the recorder.js It says to download the dependencies locally to make it work. That is what I am doing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118285/discussion-between-asim-k-t-and-nauman-zafar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try with this HTML:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/master/examples/example_simple_exportwav.html

and this JS:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/master/dist/recorder.js

This have no save button either. But it will show the status of the JS.

The example is taken from the official repo of recorderJS (https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs).

I think you missed some script from your example.

Comment: Works great ! Serves the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have a localhost on your machine to that works. If you don't know how to do it, it's not hard. I have a OSX and i use [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/), it works for Windows as well. All you need to do is:

1- install MAMP

2- copy the files to `MAMP/htdocs/`

3- open MAMP and start servers

4- access `//localhost:8888` or `//localhost` and that's it.

Let me know if it works.

Btw, where did you downloaded the project files? I don't find them, to test on my computer.

Comment: I am using wamp. Testing on localhost

Comment: Sandrina, I mistakenly was acessing project outside from my local directories instead of my localhost. It shows audio graphs in response to input but still the save option doesn't work

Comment: can you tell me where i can download the project to simulate on my computer?

Comment: You can download it here https://www.dropbox.com/s/96fhjzrjne9ymkt/htmlaudiodemo.zip?dl=0

Comment: i tried on my computer, i have the same problem as you. maybe it's missing some code from your download :/

Comment: Sandrina, I was able to record audio. Please see the Asim's answer above. Thanks for giving the problem your time.

Comment: Yes i saw, it was code missing ehehe it happens all the time :D Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

We did this for a project a while back, there are a few flags you need to enable in chrome in order for this to work, Legacy Audio Pipelining is one of them. If you need the rest, i can check.

Comment: Thanks Max for taking time to comment. I am able to record & playback sound with Asim's instructions given below.